# JQuery! How can I get background-image path with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, background

I try

```
alert($('.right').css('background-mage'));
```

but it doesn't help!?

Comment: Have you tried `background-image`? As in, spelt correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You've missed an i in the .css('background-**i**mage'). Though I haven't tried it out, I believe that it should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

`.css()` returns `null` or `undefined` when the element doesn't have a `background-image`. Also, spell it correctly, `background-image` with the *i*.